# Angular PrimeNG Breadcrumbs not changing dynamically

Tags: angular, rxjs, primeng, breadcrumbs

**Breadcrumbs component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { BreadcrumbsService } from './breadcrumbs.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumbs',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumbs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumbs.component.scss'],
})
export class BreadcrumbsComponent implements OnInit {
  home: MenuItem = { icon: 'pi pi-home', routerLink: '/' };
  items: MenuItem[] = [];

  constructor(
    private service: BreadcrumbsService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.items.subscribe((arr: MenuItem[]) => {
      this.items = arr;
      console.log(this.items);
    });
  }
}
```

In the console log, I can see the new items getting added but the p-breadcrumbs in the HTML is not getting updated.

**The HTML**

```
<p-breadcrumb styleClass="border-none mr-4" [model]="items" [home]="home"></p-breadcrumb>
```

P.S: When I tried with a simple ngFor in HTML I can see the new items getting added.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `service.items.subscribe` into the constructor?

Comment: @Stoobish yes, still it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for assigning `this.item`.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.items.subscribe((arr: MenuItem[]) => {
      this.items = arr;
      this.items = [...this.items];
    });
  }
```